# How to call a function everytime you navigate to a page using MVVMLight WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

So here is my scenario. I have a page that loads a List of bases from a database. If I navigate to the page, the constructor gets called and my LoadBases() function is called. This is great, exactly what I need.

**The problem:**

If I navigate away from the page and add some more bases to the database from a different page, and then navigate back, the constructor is not called, therefore the new Bases are not loaded into my List of bases.

**What I have tried:**

**View Model Locator in MVVMLight**

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    static ViewModelLocator()
    {
        SetupNavigation();
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<BomConfiguratorContext>();

        if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
        }
        else
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
        }

        //   SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<LoginViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<UserNavigationViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<AddNewBasesViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<AddNewBillOfMaterialsViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<AddNewOptionsViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<AddNewRulesViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<GenerateBillOfMaterialsViewModel>();

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the Main property.
    /// </summary>
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance",
        "CA1822:MarkMembersAsStatic",
        Justification = "This non-static member is needed for data binding purposes.")]

    public LoginViewModel LoginViewModel
    {
        get{ return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<LoginViewModel>(); }
    }
    public UserNavigationViewModel ManageRulesViewModel
    {
        get { return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<UserNavigationViewModel>(); }
    }
    public AddNewBasesViewModel AddNewBasesViewModel
    {
        get { return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<AddNewBasesViewModel>(); }
    }
    public AddNewBillOfMaterialsViewModel AddNewBillOfMaterialsViewModel
    {
        get { return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<AddNewBillOfMaterialsViewModel>(); }
    }
    public AddNewOptionsViewModel AddNewOptionsViewModel
    {
        get { return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<AddNewOptionsViewModel>(); }
    }
    public AddNewRulesViewModel AddNewRulesViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister<AddNewRulesViewModel>();
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<AddNewRulesViewModel>();
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<AddNewRulesViewModel>();
        }
    }
    public GenerateBillOfMaterialsViewModel GenerateBillOfMaterialsViewModel
    {
        get{return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<GenerateBillOfMaterialsViewModel>();}
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Cleans up all the resources.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Cleanup()
    {
    }

    private static void SetupNavigation()
    {
        SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister<INavigationService>();
        var navigationService = new FrameNavigationService();
        navigationService.Configure("LoginView", new Uri("/Views/LoginView.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        navigationService.Configure("UserNavigationView", new Uri("/Views/UserNavigationView.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        navigationService.Configure("AddNewBasesView", new Uri("/Views/Bases/AddNewBasesView.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        navigationService.Configure("AddNewBillOfMaterialsView", new Uri("/Views/BillOfMaterials/AddNewBillOfMaterialsView.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        navigationService.Configure("AddNewOptionsView", new Uri("/Views/Options/AddNewOptionsView.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        navigationService.Configure("AddNewRulesViewStep1", new Uri("/Views/Rules/AddNewRules/AddNewRulesStep1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        navigationService.Configure("AddNewRulesViewStep2", new Uri("/Views/Rules/AddNewRules/AddNewRulesStep2.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        navigationService.Configure("AddNewRulesViewStep3", new Uri("/Views/Rules/AddNewRules/AddNewRulesStep3.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        navigationService.Configure("AddNewRulesViewStep4", new Uri("/Views/Rules/AddNewRules/AddNewRulesStep4.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        navigationService.Configure("AddNewRulesViewStep5", new Uri("/Views/Rules/AddNewRules/AddNewRulesStep5.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        navigationService.Configure("AddNewRulesViewStep6", new Uri("/Views/Rules/AddNewRules/AddNewRulesStep6.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        navigationService.Configure("AddNewRulesViewStep7", new Uri("/Views/Rules/AddNewRules/AddNewRulesStep7.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        navigationService.Configure("GenerateBillOfMaterialsView", new Uri("/Views/BillOfMaterials/GenerateBillOfMaterialsView.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<INavigationService>(() => navigationService);
    }
}
```

**View Model Taking In INavigationService**

Just an example of how I inject the navigation service and use it to navigate pages.

```
public LoginViewModel(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, INavigationService navService)
    {
        _UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _NavigationService = navService;
        LoginCommand = new RelayCommand<IHavePassword>((IHavePassword parameter) => LoginAsync(parameter));
    }
```

**Navigating To A Page**

```
 private async void LoginAsync(IHavePassword parameter)
    {
       if( await Task<bool>.Run(() => Login(parameter)))
            _NavigationService.NavigateTo("UserNavigationView");

    }
```

**The Page I am navigating to**

This is just an example of how I use the data context in a page.

```
<local:BasePage x:Class="YAI.BomConfigurator.Desktop.Views.UserNavigationView"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YAI.BomConfigurator.Desktop"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="800"
  Title="UserNavigationView"
  DataContext="{Binding ManageRulesViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

<Border>
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer>
            <StackPanel
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center">
                <Border Background="{StaticResource BackgroundLightBrush}"
                        CornerRadius="10"
                        Padding="15 50 15 15"
                        Width="600"
                        Margin="50 50 50 0">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="I Would Like To..." 
                                   FontSize="{StaticResource FontSizeLarge}"
                                   FontFamily="{StaticResource LatoRegular}"
                                   Foreground="{StaticResource MediumBlueBrush}"
                                   Margin="0 0 0 15"/>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Margin="0 0 25 0">

                            <Button Content="Generate BOMs"
                                Margin="0 50 0 20"
                                Command="{Binding GenerateBillOfMaterialsCommand}"/>
                            <Button Content="Check Rules"
                                    Margin="0 25 0 20"
                                    Command="{Binding CheckRulesCommand}"/>
                            <Button Content="Add New Options"
                                    Margin="0 25 0 20"
                                    Command="{Binding AddNewOptionsCommand}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                            <Button Content="Add New BOMs"
                                    Margin="0 50 0 20"
                                    Command="{Binding AddNewBillOfMaterialsCommand}" />
                            <Button Content="Add New Rules"
                                    Margin="0 25 0 20"
                                    Command="{Binding AddNewRulesCommand}"/>
                            <Button Content="Add New Bases"
                                    Margin="0 25 0 20"
                                    Command="{Binding AddNewBasesCommand}"/>
                        </StackPanel>

                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

The issue with this solution is that when unregistering and re registering the view model every time it is called, when I navigate through my views which all use the datacontext AddNewRulesViewModel, it literally clears all my variables out and calls the constructor for EVERY page (there is like 7 of them that use the same view model).

So what I am looking for is a way to call my LoadBases() function only when I navigate to a specific page. Can anyone give me some advice on how to approach this?

Comment: Is there no way to broadcast a message containing the new bases such that the original page (if instantiated) will be informed of the changes?  Pub/Sub or Observer pattern.  Messenger seems like the right thing: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/d485e5b7-e6dc-4cbe-93fb-dc6311ef61a6

Comment: Ill check it out thanks.

Comment: @Selthien: How are you navigating between pages?

Comment: @mm8 I use a Navigation Service implementing the MVVMLight INavigationService. I then load all the pages in the View Model Locator, and when I need navigation I inject the INavigation interface into my view model and use it to .NavigateTo("PageIWant");

Comment: @Selthien: Please include a minimal example in your question.

Comment: I will do that right now.

Comment: @mm8 Everything has been added. If you need more just let me know. I tried to condense what I could.

Comment: @Selthien: What view are you navigating to and how is this implemented? How does it get a view model?

Comment: Ill add that part hold on.

Comment: @mm8 okay I just went ahead and added the entire view model locator

Comment: @Selthien: You forgot UserNavigationView.xaml/UserNavigationView.xaml.cs.

Comment: Is the LoadBases() located in the view model or the page? And when exaclty do you want to call it?

Comment: @mm8 The LoadBases() is located in the view model as a private function. I want it to call everytime I go to my AddNewRulesViewStep1. The 7 steps all have the same viewmodel.

Comment: @mm8 Okay I tried to add a few more details. But yes basically all I want to do is call LoadBases() which is in my AddNewRulesViewModel every time I navigate to the AddNewRulesStep1 page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I ended up fixing the issue is using an event trigger on my Page Loaded event. Here is small example of what I did.

**Trigger in xaml**

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoadAllDataCommand}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

**View Model LoadAllDataCommand**

```
LoadAllDataCommand = new RelayCommand(async () => await LoadAllDataAsync());
```

**View Model Command Action**

```
 private async Task LoadAllDataAsync()
    {
        AllBases.Clear();
        try
        {
            using (var UOW = _UnitOfWorkFactory.Create())
            {
                foreach (Base ba in await Task.Run(() => _BaseRepository.GetAll()))
                {
                    AllBases.Add(ba);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            await Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() => {
                Messenger.Default.Send(new ToastErrorMessage { Message = "Error: There was a problem with loading the data" });
            }));
        }     
    }
```

So every time the page is loaded my data is reloaded from the database with all the newly added bases.